# Rolling subtraction in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying do something like that.

```
ff = pd.DataFrame({'uid':[1,1,1,20,20,20,4,4,4],
                   'date':['09/06','10/06','11/06',
                           '09/06','10/06','11/06',
                           '09/06','10/06','11/06'],
                   'balance':[150,200,230,12,15,15,700,1000,1500],
                  'difference':[np.NaN,50,30,np.NaN,3,0,np.NaN,300,500]})
```

I have tried with rolling, but I cannot find the function or the rolling sub-class that subtracts, only sum and var and other stats.
Is there a way?
I was thinking that I can create two `df`s: one - with the first row of every uid eliminated, the second one - with the last row of every uid eliminated. But to be honest, I have no idea how to do that dynamically, for every uid.

Comment: Why did someone down vote me?! What is wrong with the question?

Comment: You probably got downvoted because you added a picture of your data instead of the code to generate the data.  If you look at the why I answered your question, I published the code to generate your dataframe.  Next or even now, modify this question to remove the image of the data and add the code to generate the data along with expected results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `groupby` with `diff`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'uid':[1,1,1,20,20,20,4,4,4],
                   'date':['09/06','10/06','11/06',
                           '09/06','10/06','11/06',
                           '09/06','10/06','11/06'],
                   'balance':[150,200,230,12,15,15,700,1000,1500]})

df['difference'] = df.groupby('uid')['balance'].diff()
```

Output:

```
   uid   date  balance  difference
0    1  09/06      150         NaN
1    1  10/06      200        50.0
2    1  11/06      230        30.0
3   20  09/06       12         NaN
4   20  10/06       15         3.0
5   20  11/06       15         0.0
6    4  09/06      700         NaN
7    4  10/06     1000       300.0
8    4  11/06     1500       500.0
```

Comment: Thank you Scott! The syntax still eludes me but it works perfectly! I mean, it seems the dataframe doesn't even need to know that there is date involved...

Comment: Diff in case is just doing a difference between rows.  Date is not considered here.  If your dates weren't in order, then you'll need to sort the dataframe first then call diff to get previous mines current row.

Comment: edited. But the ordering is not the same and might be misleading and I don't know how to change the ordering of the columns in the output dataframe so that the difference is actually on the far right.

Comment: Create a list of your in the order that you want, then use df[listname].